# AddThis and History.js - automatic redirection to wrong URL

Tags: redirect, hash, addthis, history.js

I have a problem with [AddThis](http://www.addthis.com/) widget and [History.js](https://github.com/browserstate/history.js) script.

Once user shares some page on Facebook using AddThis widget, some hashtag is appended to URL (e.g. `#.U-S_Q-q0tE8.facebook`).

Then, if user clicks such link on Facebook and goes to my website with URL e.g.: `http://domain.com/path/to/content,123.html#.U-S_Q-q0tE8.facebook`, they get redirected to `http://domain.com/path/to/.U-S_Q-q0tE8.facebook` which throws error 404.

The weird thing is that History.js is not even initialized or used. It's just embed on the site with `<script...>` tag.

Is there any solution to this? Is it possible to disable such behavior in History.js?

Answer (score 0):

I have the exact same problem, and while I don't know if you can disable the history.js behavior, you can disable the addthis hashes by adding the following before the addthis script

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
     var addthis_config = {
          data_track_clickback: false 
     } 
</script>
```

This means you wont be able to track how many click that link gets using addthis, but something like Google Analytics is able to show traffic source.

[Source](http://support.addthis.com/customer/portal/articles/381252-click-tracking)